# Ecuación con scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator

Tags: python, scipy, interpolacion

Quiero saber si es posible obtener la ecuación analítica con la cual se están calculando las interpolaciones con `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator`, o si existe alguna función para entregar 3 entradas `x`y una entrada `y` y devolver las interpolaciones y su ecuación. Gracias!